# Mixin in different routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Anyone could explain how to use **mixin** in different routes in ember

Consider an example I would like to write a method which will take care of REST API call using mixin.

```
getData: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes&year=2010&sold_in_us=1',
           type: 'GET',
           accepts: 'application/json',
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(data) {
               resolve(data);
           },
           error: function() {
               reject('DEBUG: GET Enquiries Failed');
           }
      });
    });
  }
```

Suppose I would like to use this **getData()** in different routes, What will be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com/) you can generate mixins by running `ember g mixin my-custom-ajax` which will create a file under `app/mixins` named `my-custom-ajax.js`.

In that file you would export your mixin as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.carqueryapi.com/api/0.3/?callback=?&cmd=getMakes&year=2010&sold_in_us=1',
        type: 'GET',
        accepts: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
          resolve(data);
        },
        error: function() {
          reject('DEBUG: GET Enquiries Failed');
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And in the routes that would implement your mixin you would have to import and include it:

```
import MyCustomAjaxMixin from 'yourAppName/mixins/my-custom-ajax'
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend(MyCustomAjaxMixin, {});
```